# Relational Database Design - User favorite DB design

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, rdbms

**Use case** : Save user favorite combination to database.

A user can select

1."a,b,c" as his first favorite combination.

2."a,b" as second favorite combination.

How to design a DB table for saving this information and also 
should be able to retrieve by querying using used id

select * from UserFav where userId = :userId
should return
[a,b,c] and [a,b]

### Too much redundant data with this table schema

```
userId  combination
qw1     a,b,c
qw1     b,c
```

---

Can someone guide me to design in the best possible way.

Comment: what is it that you find to redundant with that table schema ?

Comment: @GuidoG
userId and individual selection in combination.
userId is repeated twice and b,c is repeated twice.

Comment: but thats normal in any `one to many` relationship. The UserId has to repeat itself without it no relationship can be made. For the selectioin combination you need to provide more info on how it acually looks like

Comment: look at @cloudsafe answer, I think it solves your problem

Comment: @GuidoG yes. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would store it in individual rows, not as delimited strings:

```
Declare @favourites table (UserID char(3), fav_list_pos int, fav_pos int, fav_val char(1))

insert into @favourites values
  ('qw1', 1, 1, 'a')
, ('qw1', 1, 2, 'b')
, ('qw1', 1, 3, 'c')
, ('qw1', 2, 1, 'a')
, ('qw1', 2, 2, 'b')

select * from @favourites where userId = 'qw1' order by fav_list_pos, fav_pos
```

Comment: good answer, it just needs an order by on the select statement imo